# Get value based on sub-array unique value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

My `JSON` data looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "blogTitle": "How to plant a tree?",
            "categories": [{
                "CategoryID": "10",
                "CategoryTitle": "Apple Tree"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "11",
                "CategoryTitle": "Mango Tree"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "42",
                "CategoryTitle": "Banana Tree"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "blogTitle": "How to make Juice?",
            "categories": [{
                "CategoryID": "71",
                "CategoryTitle": "Apple Juice"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "72",
                "CategoryTitle": "Mango Juice"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "73",
                "CategoryTitle": "Banana Juice"
            }]

        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is to get the value of `id` by passing the value of `CategoryID`

For example: if I send `10` then I should get `1` in return because `"CategoryID": "10"` is in the same block with `"id": "1"`

**Each `CategoryID` is unique resulting in a unique value of `id`**

**What did I do?**

- Closest I came up with was using the `array.filter()` but I am able to filter `id` value give the value of `id` but how do I get the value of `id`, given `CategoryID`

Could someone please kindly help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can integrate your data, then use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this.

```js
const yourObject = {"data":[{"id":"1","blogTitle":"How to plant a tree?","categories":[{"CategoryID":"10","CategoryTitle":"Apple Tree"},{"CategoryID":"11","CategoryTitle":"Mango Tree"},{"CategoryID":"42","CategoryTitle":"Banana Tree"}]},{"id":"2","blogTitle":"How to make Juice?","categories":[{"CategoryID":"71","CategoryTitle":"Apple Juice"},{"CategoryID":"72","CategoryTitle":"Mango Juice"},{"CategoryID":"73","CategoryTitle":"Banana Juice"}]}]};

const find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId = (categoryId) => {
  for(const item of yourObject.data){
    if(item.categories && item.categories.some(r => r.CategoryID == categoryId))
      return item.id;
  }
  
  return "Not found";
}

console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(11));
console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(71));
console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(999));
```

**Simpler approach:** *using `Array#find`*

```js
const yourObject = {"data":[{"id":"1","blogTitle":"How to plant a tree?","categories":[{"CategoryID":"10","CategoryTitle":"Apple Tree"},{"CategoryID":"11","CategoryTitle":"Mango Tree"},{"CategoryID":"42","CategoryTitle":"Banana Tree"}]},{"id":"2","blogTitle":"How to make Juice?","categories":[{"CategoryID":"71","CategoryTitle":"Apple Juice"},{"CategoryID":"72","CategoryTitle":"Mango Juice"},{"CategoryID":"73","CategoryTitle":"Banana Juice"}]}]};

const find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId = (categoryId) => {
  const result = yourObject.data.find(item => 
                item.categories && item.categories.some(r => r.CategoryID == categoryId));
  
 return result ? result.id : "Not found"; 
}

console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(11));
console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(71));
console.log(find_ID_BasedOn_GivenCategoryId(999));
```

Comment: thank you for composing the answer. I am getting this error: `Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

Comment: Updated my answer, pls take a look at it @floss

Comment: thank you! it works. what if the `categoryId ` does not exists?

Comment: You can return `Not found` like the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with a combination of `some` for checking the `categoryID` that you want, for example:

```js
const data = {
    "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "blogTitle": "How to plant a tree?",
            "categories": [{
                "CategoryID": "10",
                "CategoryTitle": "Apple Tree"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "11",
                "CategoryTitle": "Mango Tree"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "42",
                "CategoryTitle": "Banana Tree"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "blogTitle": "How to make Juice?",
            "categories": [{
                "CategoryID": "71",
                "CategoryTitle": "Apple Juice"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "72",
                "CategoryTitle": "Mango Juice"
            }, {
                "CategoryID": "73",
                "CategoryTitle": "Banana Juice"
            }]

        }
    ]
};


const findId = (categoryID, { data }) => {
    const foundItem = data.find(({ categories }) => 
      categories.some(({ CategoryID }) => CategoryID == categoryID)
    );
    return foundItem ? foundItem.id : null;
}

console.log(findId(71, data))
```

Comment: You will get an error like `Cannot read property 'some' of undefined` when `categories` is `undefine` or `null`. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013846/9071943) above in more details :)

Answer (score 1):

find + some

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    blogTitle: "How to plant a tree?",
    categories: [
      {
        CategoryID: "10",
        CategoryTitle: "Apple Tree"
      },
      {
        CategoryID: "11",
        CategoryTitle: "Mango Tree"
      },
      {
        CategoryID: "42",
        CategoryTitle: "Banana Tree"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    blogTitle: "How to make Juice?",
    categories: [
      {
        CategoryID: "71",
        CategoryTitle: "Apple Juice"
      },
      {
        CategoryID: "72",
        CategoryTitle: "Mango Juice"
      },
      {
        CategoryID: "73",
        CategoryTitle: "Banana Juice"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const findId = (id) => {
  return data?.find((item) =>
    item?.categories?.some((i) => i?.CategoryID === id)
  )?.id;
};


console.log(findId("10")); //1
```

Comment: You will get an error at this like `.id;` when not found.

Comment: fix error: add optional chaining. It will return `undefined`, when not fond.